# How can I work this out? Multiple timer for javascript for different rizzles

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, reactjs

I have a database of rizzles and each one has a duration. I need to set a timer for each one (under determinated conditions) but I would not know how to handle that.

And of course, the timer if runs, have to be saved between pages, so I was thinking to do on the server side. It is a web application with React and NodeJS. I would show some code but I don't know what to write. I was thinking to a vector of idrizzle and duration in server side, but I would not know how to implement it.

Any ideas or suggestions?

EDIT:

I try to give you more details:
*- If the riddle is “open”, the author will see all current answers (updated every second), and a count-down showing the remaining time.*

Means that every riddle has a duration, and if there are multiple riddle opened, I must have multiple "setInterval" or something that just decrease the duration and show to the user.

*- selecting an “open” riddle, gives him/her the opportunity to reply (without showing any of the other replies, of course). Any user may provide at most one reply to each riddle, and it cannot be modified after submission. In the reply to an open riddle, a count-down shows the remaining time. If the remaining time is less than 50%, the first hint is shown. If the remaining time is less than 25%, also the second hint is shown.*

This is pretty much the same. I need to take the countdown, probably from the front end.

In my DB i have only the full duration

EDIT 2:

An idea I came up with is to create a copy of my state and using to decrease the duration, problem is that I can see the decrease only when I close and open again:

```
//------TIMER------------
function decreaseDuration(){
  copy.map(e=>{
    if(e.state===1){
      if(e.duration>0){
        e.duration=e.duration-1;
      }
    }
  })
}
setInterval(decreaseDuration(),1000);
```

Is there any way I can live update the countdown?

EDIT 2:
Now, the requirement are now clear: I need to do an API polling to the server and get the time. But yet I don't know how to work this out. I was thinking to create a timestamp column on the answer table and call for it every second

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what is a rizzle?

Comment: I tried some setInterval on the front-end page but did not work out. Rizzle as a quiz, like a question to answer. As soon as the first answer is inserted in the database, a timer should run with the duration. Also every other user should see the timer if the server is active

Comment: You should show an example of what you are trying to accomplish here. Go into the specifics. As is your question is unanswerable in my opnion. The question is to broad and there are a lot of details missing.

Comment: I tried to add some details, I am quite confused about it too

Comment: It is still not fully clear to me what you are trying to achieve and where you are struggling. As I understand it you want a countdown to show the duration left for any riddle. Consider this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04evbto3/3/) for a basic countdown.

Comment: did you consider using websockets to keep live connections from users? you would be able to create "room" for each riddle on server side with an independent timer state. Each room would send timer updates to connected browsers to keep them in sync

Comment: Can't use socket. Requirements says API polling

Comment: The only thing you need to poll for is the new start of a riddle. On page load you fetch all already started riddle timers (a timestamp of the start, or better calculated end) show all countdowns for such initialized riddles. And then you call your api to get notified about newly started riddles after that  with polling. For better indexing it might be a good idea to set the calculated end time for a riddle instead of the start. You update the timer clientside, and validate answers - if they are still within the time of the riddle - serverside.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! I did arrive to the same solution